# Showing $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x)^k (2k+1) \ln(2k+1) = \frac{-2C}{\pi}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, summation-method, catalans-constant

While I was playing around with divergent summation, I noticed that the following appears to be true:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x)^k (2k+1) \ln(2k+1) = \frac{-2C}{\pi}$$

where $C = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$ is Catalan's constant. How can I show this?

---

I'll note that the above is Abel summation, and so different choices of divergent summation should work; for example, I suspect:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{2n}{n+k}}{\binom{2n}{n}} (-1)^k (2k+1)\ln(2k+1) = \frac{-2C}{\pi}  $$

The reason I mention this latter limit is because I've seen [some similar limits performed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2826451) with the factor of $\binom{2n}{n+k}$, and so I hope that this might make the problem tractable (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2827591) and the comments and answer). I'll accept an answer that proves either of the above limits, since I suspect them to be equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $0<x<1$ we have $f(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(2k+1)(-x)^k=(1-x)/(1+x)^2$.

Using Frullani integral $\log z=\int_0^\infty(e^{-t}-e^{-zt})\,dt/t$, we obtain $$F(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-x)^k(2k+1)\log(2k+1)=\int_0^\infty\big(f(x)-f(xe^{-2t})\big)\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt$$ (still for $0<x<1$); the change $\sum\int\mapsto\int\sum$ is justified by absolute convergence. Moreover, it is easy to check that $(a,x)\mapsto\big(f(x)-f(ax)\big)/(1-a)$ is bounded on $0<a,x<1$, so that we may take $x\to1^-$ under the integral sign (by dominated convergence): $$F(1^-)=-\int_0^\infty f(e^{-2t})\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt=-\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh^2 t}\frac{dt}{t}.$$ Now, using the following integral (say, a special case of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)) $$g(x):=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cosh 2xt}{\cosh^2 t}\,dt=\frac{x\pi}{\sin x\pi}\qquad(|x|<1)$$ we get $F(1^-)=-\int_0^{1/2}g(x)\,dx$, giving the result by [$2C=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\,dx}{\sin x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4281469).

Comment: This gives me joy to read! The Frullani trick is really quite nice - I had even been reading about it earlier yesterday but hadn't thought to use it. Now I've got to play around with some other sums like this...